# Setting in Maximo Anywhere where any url specified for worklight server in build.properties cant be connected anymore through build apps

Tags: ios, maximo-anywhere

**In  summary**, I have built the .ipa from a macbook pro and install it into an ipad. The app is installed successfully, but are unable to connect to load balancer url for mobile first.

All url that was specified in worklight server in build.properties are not able to connect anymore (using all apps that was built in offline wifi). This issue happen to both testing and production environment.

**Since the build is run in offline wifi, are there are settings or cache or log that store the list of url that wont be connected by apps anymore?**

**environment:**
testing and production: both have jvm url, webserver url and load balancer url which can be use to connect to server mobile first.

**Steps in building and running the app:**

1) change the build.properties to connect to load balancer url for worklight.

2) turn off wifi so that no adapter and oslc deployed into mobile first server

3) run build all

4) .ipa built and installed into ipad

5) in app setting, it is using the load balancer url.

6) app is launch, but no web resource download and when try to log in, error service is not available shown

**troubleshoot for built app:**

1) in app setting, tap the use custom url and change the load balancer url to webserver url

2) launch app, and web resource donwload is shown. able to log in

3) repeat step 1 for jvm url.

4) launch app, and web resource donwload is shown. able to log in

**Using app from app store.**

1) download and install any apps from app store (iOS). changed the custom url in setting to loadbalancer url. app is launch, got web resource download and able to log in.

**ps:**

1) no redeploy of war file

2) the app from app store works fine before and after the app was build from build server

3) macbook is in offline wifi during build process, so that no oslc and adapter deployed to server

Answer (score 0):

We are running windows and android, but I’ll attempt to help you out and hope for the best. Is SSL configured in both the web server and the load balancer? Also- another thing to change when changing urls is the OSLC and MaxRest URLs in your Maximo system properties.

Comment: SSL is configured, but should not be the main problem, since both environment uses the same wildcard certificate, and can be connected using maximo anywhere app from apple store. Both oslc and webappurl was also configured in system properties

Comment: By the way, the configuration i am looking for should be in source code for each app in ios. I am using Xcode 8.2.1 to build the .ipa file.